# How to set visibility true of one button onclick of another button in listView - android

Tags: android

I want to set the visibility to true of btnProductDetailMinus to true on click of btnProductDetailAddToCart. This is my code.

```
public class ProductVariantAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ProductVariant> productVariants = new ArrayList<>();
    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView productVariantName;
        TextView productVariantMrp;
        TextView productVariantSellPrice;
        Button btnProductDetailAddToCart, btnProductDetailPlus, btnProductDetailQty, btnProductDetailMinus;
    }

    public ProductVariantAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductVariant> productVariants) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productVariants = productVariants;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_product_variant, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productVariantName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantName);
            holder.productVariantMrp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantMrp);
            holder.productVariantSellPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantSellPrice);
            holder.btnProductDetailAddToCart = (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailAddToCart);
            holder.btnProductDetailPlus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailPlus);
            holder.btnProductDetailQty = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailQty);
            holder.btnProductDetailMinus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailMinus);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ProductVariant productVariant = (ProductVariant) getItem(position);
        if (productVariant != null) {
            holder.productVariantName.setText(productVariant.getVariant().getVariantName());
            holder.productVariantMrp.setText(productVariant.getMrp().toString());
            holder.productVariantSellPrice.setText(productVariant.getSellPrice().toString());
            holder.btnProductDetailAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Utility.displayToast("wonderful");
                    holder.btnProductDetailMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "product variant is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productVariants.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return productVariants.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return productVariants.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

But its giving error "Variable holder is accessed from within inner class. needs to declared final"

This is the line giving error.

```
 holder.btnProductDetailMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Move this line out of the `if (convertView == null)`

```
holder = new ViewHolder();
```

Comment: In that case this line will give error. holder = new ViewHolder(); How we will create the holder than?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `final ViewHolder holder = null;` instead of `ViewHolder holder = null;`

1. You can just make it a **Global variable**.
2. set   `public static class ViewHolder` instead of `private class ViewHolder`

Comment: In that case this line will give error. holder = new ViewHolder(); How we will create the holder than?

Comment: Set `ViewHolder holder;` Remove `null`

Comment: set   `public static class ViewHolder` instead of `private class ViewHolder`

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Check this

Answer (score 0):

Assign holder tot a final variabele:

```
final ViewHolder fHolder = holder;
```

Then in onClick:

```
fHolder.btnProductDetailMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach that I follow is create a Map or List in Adapter class and onClick set value and that collection, and in adapter getView method check for the collection value. .

Checkout the below code.

```
public class ProductVariantAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ProductVariant> productVariants = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Integer, Boolean> visibilityMap = new HashMap<>();
    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView productVariantName;
        TextView productVariantMrp;
        TextView productVariantSellPrice;
        Button btnProductDetailAddToCart, btnProductDetailPlus, btnProductDetailQty, btnProductDetailMinus;
    }

    public ProductVariantAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductVariant> productVariants) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productVariants = productVariants;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_product_variant, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productVariantName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantName);
            holder.productVariantMrp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantMrp);
            holder.productVariantSellPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantSellPrice);
            holder.btnProductDetailAddToCart = (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailAddToCart);
            holder.btnProductDetailPlus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailPlus);
            holder.btnProductDetailQty = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailQty);
            holder.btnProductDetailMinus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailMinus);
            holder.btnProductDetailAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = (int)v.getTag();
                    Utility.displayToast("wonderful");
                    visibilityMap.put(position, true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.btnProductDetailAddToCart.setTag(position);

        ProductVariant productVariant = (ProductVariant) getItem(position);
        if (productVariant != null) {
            holder.productVariantName.setText(productVariant.getVariant().getVariantName());
            holder.productVariantMrp.setText(productVariant.getMrp().toString());
            holder.productVariantSellPrice.setText(productVariant.getSellPrice().toString());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "product variant is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(visibilityMap.containsKey(position) && visibilityMap.get(position)){
           holder.btnProductDetailMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
           holder.btnProductDetailMinus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }   

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productVariants.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return productVariants.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return productVariants.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```